# Issue with delete command in gridview - must declare scalar

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been working on this gridview and it seems like everything should work but I get an error "Must declare scalar variable" when i execute the delete command.  The really weird thing is, if I remove the existing update command and turn the delete command into the update command, it works and deleted the record.  Any idea why it works as an update but not as delete?  I'm using .net 3.5

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="Project_List" 
        Width="800px" EditRowStyle-Width="800px" RowStyle-BackColor="#D8D8D8" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#ffffff">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Updates">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="gridEditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="gridDeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.png" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="gridUpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/images/save.png" />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="gridCancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.png" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="project_id" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="functional_sponsor" HeaderText="Functional Sponsor" SortExpression="functional_sponsor" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="program_name" HeaderText="Program" SortExpression="program_name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="project_name" HeaderText="Project" SortExpression="project_name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="approval_status" HeaderText="Approval Status" SortExpression="approval_status" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="approved_date" HeaderText="Approved Date" SortExpression="approved_date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="approved_by" HeaderText="Approved By" SortExpression="approved_by" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="charge_code" HeaderText="Charge Code" SortExpression="charge_code" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="open_date" HeaderText="Open Date" SortExpression="open_date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="close_date" HeaderText="Close Date" SortExpression="close_date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="project_sponsor" HeaderText="Sponsor" SortExpression="project_sponsor" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="project_manager" HeaderText="Project Manager" SortExpression="project_manager" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="technical_lead" HeaderText="Technical Lead" SortExpression="technical_lead" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="approved_amount" HeaderText="Approved Amount ($K)" SortExpression="approved_amount" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="requested_amount" HeaderText="Requested Amount ($K)" SortExpression="requested_amount" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Project_List" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectDB %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [vw_IT_Portfolio] ORDER BY [functional_sponsor], [program_name], [project_name]"
        DeleteCommand="EXEC [Utilities_SN].[dbo].[sp_Delete_ITPortfolio_Record] @projectID = @project_id"
        UpdateCommand="EXEC [Utilities_SN].[dbo].[sp_Update_ITPortfolio_Record]
                        @projectID = @project_id
                       ,@functionalSponsor = @functional_sponsor
                       ,@program = @program_name
                       ,@projectName = @project_name
                       ,@approvalStatus = @approval_status
                       ,@approvedDate = @approved_date
                       ,@approvedBy = @approved_by
                       ,@chargeCode = @charge_code
                       ,@openDate = @open_date
                       ,@closeDate = @close_date
                       ,@sponsor = @project_sponsor
                       ,@projectManager = @project_manager
                       ,@technicalLead = @technical_lead
                       ,@approvedAmount = @approved_amount">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Type="Int32" Name="project_id"></asp:Parameter>
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Type="Int32" Name="project_id"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="functional_sponsor"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="program_name"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="project_name"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="approval_status"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="approved_date"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="approved_by"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="charge_code"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="open_date"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="close_date"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="project_sponsor"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="project_manager"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="technical_lead"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Type="Decimal" Name="approved_amount"></asp:Parameter>
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GridView set the DataKeyNames =  project_id

ASPX page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="Project_List" 
    Width="800px" EditRowStyle-Width="800px" RowStyle-BackColor="#D8D8D8" 
    AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#ffffff" DataKeyNames="project_id">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Updates">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="gridEditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" ToolTip="Edit" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="gridDeleteButton" runat="server" CommandArgument="Delete" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.png" ToolTip="Delete"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="gridUpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/images/save.png" ToolTip="Update"/>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="gridCancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.png" ToolTip="Cancel"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="project_id" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="functional_sponsor" HeaderText="Functional Sponsor" SortExpression="functional_sponsor" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="program_name" HeaderText="Program" SortExpression="program_name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="project_name" HeaderText="Project" SortExpression="project_name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="approval_status" HeaderText="Approval Status" SortExpression="approval_status" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="approved_date" HeaderText="Approved Date" SortExpression="approved_date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="approved_by" HeaderText="Approved By" SortExpression="approved_by" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="charge_code" HeaderText="Charge Code" SortExpression="charge_code" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="open_date" HeaderText="Open Date" SortExpression="open_date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="close_date" HeaderText="Close Date" SortExpression="close_date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="project_sponsor" HeaderText="Sponsor" SortExpression="project_sponsor" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="project_manager" HeaderText="Project Manager" SortExpression="project_manager" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="technical_lead" HeaderText="Technical Lead" SortExpression="technical_lead" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="approved_amount" HeaderText="Approved Amount ($K)" SortExpression="approved_amount" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="requested_amount" HeaderText="Requested Amount ($K)" SortExpression="requested_amount" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Project_List" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectDB %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [vw_IT_Portfolio] ORDER BY [functional_sponsor], [program_name], [project_name]"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [vw_IT_Portfolio] WHERE [project_id] = @project_id" 

    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [vw_IT_Portfolio] SET [functional_sponsor] = @functional_sponsor, [program_name] = @program_name, [project_name] = @project_name, [approval_status] = @approval_status, [approved_date] = @approved_date, [approved_by] = @approved_by, [charge_code] = @charge_code, [open_date] = @open_date, [close_date] = @close_date, [project_sponsor] = @project_sponsor, [project_manager] = @project_manager, [technical_lead] = @technical_lead, [approved_amount] = @approved_amount, [requested_amount] = @requested_amount WHERE [project_id] = @project_id">
    <DeleteParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="project_id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Type="Int32" Name="project_id"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="functional_sponsor"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="program_name"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="project_name"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="approval_status"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="approved_date"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="approved_by"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="charge_code"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="open_date"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="close_date"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="project_sponsor"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="project_manager"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="technical_lead"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Type="Decimal" Name="approved_amount"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="requested_amount" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```